# Android import fingerprint package on Lollipop

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility, fingerprint

I plan to add fingerprint feature to my Android app. I understand that the Fingerprint API is available on Android M only, so I plan to do something like this in the source code

```
import android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

    private FingerprintManager fingerprintManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            this.fingerprintManager = this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(FingerprintManager.class);
        } else {
          // disable fingerprint related components
        }
    }
}
```

It seemed working fine when I tried to install the apk on the Nexus 4 running Android Lollipop, but I am not sure if it will still work on other devices. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: WHat are you looking for here?  That's the basics of how to do it-  protect any version specific code with a version check.  Obviously you need to do this around ever instance of using fingerprintManager.

Comment: I am thinking the app may crash because I import the package and declare the variable but run the apk on the environment which does not have any reference of them. If that's the common way to use the version specific code, I will feel safe to do it.

Comment: This is common.  It won't crash unless you try to actually use the variable in a version that's too low (exception:  anything below 2.3 might crash, as they had a much stricter check.  On 2.3 they switched to a check on use policy, on 2.2 and before they checked on boot for any reference to an unknown api).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I cannot seem to find the documentation about the api check on api 2.2 and 2.3. Would you kindly point me to the location? Thanks.